# Why is it starting a new line before it should in PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, file, line, newline

I'm having a problem with arrays and file writing, what I want to do is take one file, and copy it onto another file, except with formatting added to it.

To be specific, this:

Line 1
Line 2
Line 3

Would become this:

```
<br /><hr />Line 1  
<br /><hr />Line 2  
<br /><hr />Line 3
```

And I've sorta done that, but something weird happens. Instead of formatting all on one line, it linebreaks and keeps going. Like this

```
<br />1
THE END<br />7
THE END<br />0
THE END<br />Red
THE END<br />Silent
THE END<br />No ChangesTHE END
```

My code for this is:

```
<?php

 $filename1 = "directorx_OLDONE.txt";
 $filename2 = "directorx_NEWONE.txt";
 $file1 = fopen($filename1, "r") or exit ("No");
 $file2 = fopen($filename2, "w") or exit ("No");

 while (!feof($file1)){
      $listArrayf1[] = fgets($file1);
 }
 fclose($file1);

 echo var_dump($listArrayf1) . "<br /><br />";


 $entries = count($listArrayf1) - 1;

 echo $entries;

 for($i=0;$i<=$entries;$i++){
      $listArrayf2[] = "<br />".$listArrayf1[$i]."THE END";
      fwrite($file2, $listArrayf2[$i]);
 }
 fclose($file2); 

 echo var_dump($listArrayf2);
 /*

 Open file1, r
 Open file2, w
 While it's not the end of the file, add each line of file1 to an array.
 Count the number of lines in file1 and call it Entries. -1 because gotta start at 0.

 Make a new array with the values of the old one, but with tags before and after it.

 */
 ?>
```

I'm sure there's a better way to accomplish the ultimate goal I'm trying, which is detecting certain words entered into a form, (There's probably a better way than making a formatted and non-formatted copy of what gets entered.) but my PHP vocab is limited and I'd like to figure out the long, prerequisite hard ways before learning how to do em easier.

At first I thought that it was because I was writing the OLDFILE manually, using the return key. So I made a script to write it using \n instead and it changed nothing.

Comment: Yes you have to hit space 4 times on every line if you fail to use editor supporting indentation of code blocks! Or, you can use backticks `\`` too

Comment: ">Oh god do I have to hit space 4 times on EVERY line???"  Just select the block and click the curly brackets to format the code

Comment: Highlight your code and click the {} button. It will indent it for you automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eh :)

At first, please take a look on [var_dump](http://sk.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) and check what the function is returning (nothing, so correct usage is `var_dump( ...); echo "<br />";`)

Second, `fgets` reads string **including** newline character, so I guess you see in your string something like this:

```php
string( 10) "abcdefghi
"
```

So you have to remove newline manually for example with [trim](http://sk.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

Next, I'd recommend to (at least) take a look at [foreach](http://sk.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

So I'd wrote the whole loop as:

```php
foreach( $listArrayf1 as $row){
  $row = "<br /><hr />". trim( $row)."THE END";
  fwrite($file2, $row);
  $listArrayf2[] = $row;
}
```

You may also use `foreach( $listArrayf1 as &$row)` and in the end `$listArrayf1` will contain exactly the same as `$listArrayf2`. When you need to preserve all other spaces, you should probably use `$row = substr( $row, 0, -1);`

btw: you can write normal code, mark it in textarea and by hitting `ctrl+k` it'll get indented by 4 spaces

Comment: Using `trim` like that is not a good idea: it will strip *all* whitespace.

Comment: @Jon just from the beginning and from the end, none white spaces in the middle of the text will be stripped. My experiences are that this is welcomed behavior in most of web applications. And I've added example with `substr` which is correct when you need to preserve spaces.

Comment: @Vyktor: There may be spaces at the beginning which are needed for formatting. And the substr code will not work correctly if there is a CRLF (two chars) at the end of the line. In general, things are not always as simple as we 'd like :)

Comment: @Jon yeah, you're right but the main goal was to print just line contents... If you knew that you're going to be needing extra spaces from the end/beginning you'd use different method or function. But I still think that the need of preserving space at the beginning and the end of string is more rare than common (in php). And lets be honest we all do compromises between what's perfect (and how would we like things to be done) and the time/effort need for implementing certain method.

Comment: @Vyktor: I 'm offering advice on how you can make the code better. Feel free to disregard it or not. That's all.

Comment: @Vyktor: I 've written an answer, so that's they way I 'd do it.

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` returns the newline character at the end of each line as part of its input. That's where your "extra" newline comes from.

Change this

```
$listArrayf1[] = fgets($file1);
```

to this:

```
$listArrayf1[] = rtrim(fgets($file1), "\r\n");
```

This will remove the newline characters from the end of the return value and make your strings format as intended.

**However**, as you said yourself you are really doing things in a roundabout way. You could read all of file1 into an array with just

```
$listArrayf1 = file($filename1);
```

That's it. No loops, no `fopen`, no problems with newlines. It pays to look for the most fitting way of doing things.

Comment: @afuzzyllama: Whatever happens to be in your input file. I 'm just being cautious here.

Comment: Hey thanks to both of you, you each had a part to the puzzle. I needed to use rtrim (I'm guessing rtrim lets you target characters with \r and trim defaults to whitespace?) and foreach but also learned how to bypass a ton of busy work with the file reading. Had no idea you could do it like that. You both helped a lot, but I'm finding I have a lot more questions. I'll try to answer them myself, but I think I'll be back here a lot more. For the future, how do I comment to both of you?

Comment: @user1159454: If you do not know the difference between [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) and [`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php), you should look them up in the php online manual.